# Brew update error

Tags: homebrew

I am using a macbook and have ruby installed on my machine. I wanted to install a ruby gem but wanted to update HomeBrew first. I ran *'brew update'* in my home folder and got this error:

```
 error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
Library/Formula/vcprompt.rb
 Please move or remove them before you can merge.
 Aborting
 Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I tried going in to the library/formula folder but it doesn't exist on my machine. I am not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

cd /usr/local && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD

or if it fails

cd /usr/local && sudo git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pid. What does this command do?

Comment: it corrects the references from the last pull, I'm not the git hero at all, but it works for me ;-) Had the same issue...

Comment: it resets the files to REPO Master.